# Retrieve rows where all related data meets specified criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `job` table and a `visit` table. A job can have multiple visits. I need to retrieve all jobs, which haven't been set as paid, with all visits tied to that job set as completed.

So basically I need to only retrieve a job if:

- It hasn't been paid `(paid = 'N')`
- All the visits tied to that job are set as complete `(status = 2)`

Obviously doing the following doesn't work as it will return any result where `job.paid = 'N' and visit.status = '2'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   job INNER JOIN visit 
       ON job.id = visit.job_id 
WHERE  job.paid = 'N' AND 
       visit.status = 2;
```

I could retrieve the results, and run additional queries to check that all the visits for a job are complete, but I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve the data in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.ID  -- <<== add some columns here
FROM    job a INNER JOIN visit b ON a.id = b.job_ID
WHERE   a.paid = 'N'
GROUP   BY a.ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.Status) = 1 AND MAX(b.status) = 2
```

Comment: You have the paid column in the wrong table though - unless the OP made a mistake in his post.  He shows the paid column being in the JOB table, not the VISITS table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM job j 
WHERE j.paid = 'N' AND 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM visit WHERE job_id = j.id AND visit.status <> 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM job WHERE paid = 'N' AND id NOT IN (
SELECT job_id FROM visit WHERE status != 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility of a Job that doesn't have any Visit records associated with it, and you'd want to still return that Job record if it has paid = 'N', then you'll want to LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM JOB j
LEFT JOIN VISIT v
ON j.id = v.job_id
WHERE j.paid = 'N'
AND j.id NOT IN (SELECT job_id FROM visit WHERE status != 2)
```